# the_content() "crashes" for single pages

Tags: loop, content, the-content

I have big trouble with the_content() for single.php.

**Whats my problem?**

- the_content() doesn't give any output on single pages
- furthermore it crashes (no other PHP code below the function call is executed
- There are no PHP or database errors shown
- On all other page and post types the_content() works

**What I have done/checked so far**

- deactivated all plugings -> no success
- used original Wordpress themes -> no success
- checked twice if the_content() is inside the loop -> it is inside
- tried to use $post->post_content -> gives output, but I want to use the_content()
- $textt = get_the_content(); echo $textt; -> Works also, so where's the difference between get_the_content and the_content, which keeps the_content from working as supposed to

So it seems that the problem is theme and plugin independent. I use Wordpress 3.8 and also tried to reinstall the via the update function.

Comment: Do you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled? Check server logs, sometimes PHP gets confused so bad it crashes Apache before it can generate error.

Comment: Can you copy / paste `The Loop` into your question? Have you tried the default theme?

Comment: Post your loop code and anything else that could affect it.

Answer (score 0):

the_content( ); vs  get_the_content(); The different is pretty simple actually. If you find yourself annoyed with formatting of the content, more specifically the **added p-tags that WordPress puts into the content** that you didn’t. Just use **get_the_content();** and you will remove those tags.

Normally the **get_the_content()** tag returns the content WITHOUT formatting. Only **the_content()** will print the content WITH formatting.

> echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

Comment: Yeah, but I want to use the_content(). I asked for the difference to find the point, which keeps the_content() from working correctly. So also apply_filters('the_content') is broken. So I think if I could get the "the_content" filter fixed, the_content() would also work again. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: use this code pass second perimeter value.                  echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

Comment: Unfortunaely this doesn't work, because the 'the_content' filter is broken. But I don't know why. Wordpress is freshly installed and even with twentyforteen theme and no plugins it doesn't work for single page. For main page and pages it does work.

Comment: This code is worked on 3.8 theme fourteen in single.php so your code in mistake please add your code.